# difficulty in building ffmpeg for windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I am making an app in which i want to use ffmpeg library.I have successfully compiled the library in windows,but i have not seen the ffmpeg.so,but i got the ffmpeg.exe file.Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: "for windows" and "android" tag + .so? Clean this mess up a bit please

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg.exe path. If you are creating video image through ffmpeg then use this code:

```
    function create_video_image_only($v_file,$thumb) {
$cmd = 'C:\inetpub\vhosts\domain-name\httpdocs\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -itsoffset -4 -i "'.$v_file.'" -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 105x74 "'.UP_FILES_FS_PATH.'/image_video/'.$thumb.'.jpg"' ; 
exec($cmd);
```

}

Comment: Sir actually i want to know that how to make the ffmpeg.so file.I have just got ffmpeg.exe after compilation of ffmpeg lib.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build `.DLL`s and link to them (this is what `.SO`s are in Windows world), then you appear to not built the binaries successfully yet.

The key is to use `--enable-shared` configuration setting when building, so that your output includes `libavcodec.dll` and its cousins.

You don't have to build on your own, [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) already has prebuilt binaries: "Shared" are those DLL/SOs, and "Dev" are static libraries to link into your project to make a connection between your code and FFmpeg built separately.